How to get only values as Integer from SQL table using Spring Boot?
I want only value from the column which is Integer type.
I have this code here as:
In Controller:
@GetMapping("/rating/{id}")
Rating findRating(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Optional<Rating> rating = runRepository.findRating(id);
    System.out.println("rating is -------"+rating.get());
    return rating.get();
}

In Repository:
public Optional<Rating> findRating(Integer id) {
    return jdbcClient.sql
            ("select rating from movie where id = :id")
            .param("id", id).query(Rating.class).optional();
}

The Output is:
rating is -------Rating[rating=9.0]

The problem with this code is that I will have to trim this value and then I can play around (calculating average etc) with my value 9.0, but I want to make it easier with code. Is there any option?
I tried the above snippet and I expect only the value rather than the column name and value.

You are returning a Rating why are you operating on the String?

Did u define Rating as a record containing string perhaps? Just redefine it to use int?

@M.Deinum @J Ashgarov Indeed, Rating is a record with parameter rating as double. public record Rating(double rating) { }
So, should I use an Integer instead of Record? i didn't get you..

You should extract nested attribute and convert it to integer return rating.get().getRating().intValue(); (null checks on your own)

Further more, I belive that you will only get some answers about boxing the value. That is the easiest approach way.
